# Kafka + how to exclude folder that not related to any topic folders

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka Custer with 3 nodes ( all machines are RHEL 7.9 version )

all topics and their partitions are located under folder  `/var/kafka/kafka-logs`

Kafka broker service is very sensitive when any folder under `/var/kafka/kafka-logs` isn't part of the topics and partitions - in that case broker will failed with exception about directory that isn't topic name

so my Question is - how to exclude folder from logs-dirs , so Kafka will not complain and failed about the folder that isn't a topic?

the reason that I asked this Question is because we want to use the Kafka disk for other storage specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do so. Kafka will fail, as expected.

One option would be to wrap the `kafka-server-start` script with some shell process that'll remove anything unrelated to Kafka

Other option is to limit Unix permissions to that folder such that only a `kafka` user can read/write and ensure only the broker process runs under that user

> want to use the Kafka disk for other storage specification

You can use the disk. You cannot use that directory